# Ubuntu 22.04: perl ExtUtils::Embed is broken for ldopts

Tags: perl

Running `perl -MExtUtils::Embed -e ldopts` results in unusable output:

`-Wl,-E  -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.34/CORE -lperl -ldl -lm -lpthread -lc -lcrypt`

There is, in fact *no* `libperl.so` anywhere in the system.  There are, however, `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libperl.so.5.34` and `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libperl.so.5.34.0` in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`.  Not only is this directory missing from the output above, but `libperl.so` as a symlink there to `libperl.so.5.34` or `libperl.so.5.34.0` is *also* missing.

Note that Makefiles usually use the output of `-e ccopts` and `-e ldopts` to set arguments correctly with respect to the environment rather than hardcoding them.  Now, with the ExtUtils::Embed module broken, reliable and portable builds are impossible.  (Think, e.g. dockerized apps).

How did this get so royally fubar-ed?  How can this be fixed?

**EDIT/UPDATE:** As suggested in the comments, the`libperl-dev` package *is* installed. (`apt-get` says so).

**UPDATE 2:** The easiest fix may be in the `libperl-dev` package, which can install a `libperl.so` symlink in the original location of the libraries (`/usr/local/lib`?) as well. Then `Embed.pm` wouldn't need to change, as its output would work, thus preserving the dynamic settings in Makefiles too.

Comment: AFAIK the symlink should be provided by the `libperl-dev` package - have you installed it?

Comment: *"How did this get so royally fubar-ed?"* - simply by you not installing all requirements. Everything is provided by libperl-dev - see  https://packages.ubuntu.com/it/jammy/amd64/libperl-dev/filelist

Comment: @steeldriver, according to apt-get, yes.

Comment: if the symlink was deleted, then reinstalling the package should be sufficient to re-create it

Comment: @steeldriver, I tried that after posting.  Result: `libperl.a` and `libperl.so` (a symlink) were properly installed in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` (how?!), but `Embed -e ldopts` stayed broken. I suspect the Ubuntu builders _moved_ the libraries from their original location (probably the CORE directory) to a "standard" location. If so, they forgot to adjust `Embed.pm`.

Comment: On second thought, the how is easily explained under the hypothesis that the libraries were moved.  Now, the install script for the `libperl-dev` package can simply _assume_ the libraries are in the "right" place and go straight there.